# How inexact differential shows work is a path function

Tags: thermodynamics, work

While my professor defining the work , he says the work is the taken as inexact differential
and also says this shows that work is path dependent function but there was no reasoning how inexact differential proves work is a path function
can some one explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A $1$-form $F = F_i\text dx^i$ can be integrated along a path $\gamma : t\mapsto x(t)$ giving :
$$\int_{\gamma} F  = \int F_i \frac{\text dx^i}{\text dt}\text dt$$

If $\gamma$ is a loop encircling a surface $\Sigma$, by [Stokes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem), we have :
$$\int_{\gamma} F = \int_{\Sigma}\text dF$$
Now, if $\text dF = 0$, the integral of $F$ around any ([null homotopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Null-homotopy)) closed path vanishes. If $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are two path with the same end points, then we can build a loop $\gamma$ by first following $\gamma_1$ and then $\gamma_2$ in the reverse order and we get (if $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are [homotopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy)) :
$$0 = \int_{\gamma} F = \int_{\gamma_1} F- \int_{\gamma_2} F$$
Therefore the integral of $F$ is depending only on the path. On the other hand, if $\text dF \neq 0$, then this integral is path dependent.

Another way, maybe more familiar in physics is the following : using the [Poincaré lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar%C3%A9_lemma), if $\text dF = 0$ then, there is (at least locally) a $0$-form $V$ (ie a function) such that $\text dV$. In that case :
$$\int_{\gamma} F = \int_{\gamma}\text dV = V(b) - V(a)$$
In other words, if $\text dF \neq 0$ then $F$ does not derive from a potential.